# What is the difference between the residual, lack of fit and pure error In F test for Regression Analysis?

Tags: regression, anova, f-test, sums-of-squares

What is the difference between the residual, lack of fit and pure error and how to calculate each of them in ANOVA F test for nonlinear regression?
[image]

Comment: What software created this table? // Why do you say this is a nonlinear regression?

Comment: @Dave, the answer that OP wrote linked to Penn State's Stat 501. So, it's highly likely "nonlinear" was a typo. It's the regular lack of fit and pure error. If we have any post, we can leave that here or make a duplicate. Otherwise an outline of what these are can be written as an answer (if no one does, I might give it a try).